# Simple Jquery Slider with Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

I'm very new with jQuery, I'm trying to learn some new stuff here.

I found a [simple tutorial](http://www.webchiefdesign.co.uk/blog/simple-jquery-slideshow/index.php?page=2) on the internet -

I like the tutorial, but I want to add some additional features like additional adding buttons at the bottom of the slider. e.g

- slide1 will show the div of slide1
- slide2 will show the div of slide2 and so on...

How can i do this? This will be very useful for me.

```
<div id="slideshow">  
<div id="slideshowWindow">

<div class="slide">
<p>Slide 1</p>
</div>

<div class="slide">
<p>Slide 2</p>
</div>

<div class="slide">
<p>Slide 3</p>
</div>

</div><!--/slideshowWindow-->
</div><!--/slideshow-->


<div class="navigation">
<a href="">Slide1 Button</a> | <a href="">Slide2 Button</a> | <a href="">Slide3     Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are following the tutorial , then on part 3 you may find two links which make the divs previous or next and for that obviously the id of that particular div would be passed through the tags.

Comment: yeah i read part3, but i can't seem to edit it to the way i like it. it's just to advanced for me. :(

Comment: So you want to remove the next , prev button in the example and add your own buttons with similar or somewhat your functionality?

Comment: Yes, I would like to add my own buttons.  e.g

slide1 will show the div of slide1 and

slide2 will show the div of slide2 and so on...

Comment: Paste some code so that I can help you, if you are willing to use the same example in the link.

Comment: there i pasted my html, it's very similar to the tutorial, i just changed the image into a paragraph, also i added a class navigation below the slider,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this [tutorial](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/)  answered my question.